# Akka Http Client :Custom headers

Tags: scala, rest, akka-http

I am trying to use Akka-Http for invoking REST url. I am following [this](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.10/scala/http/client-side/request-level.html#Using_the_Future-Based_API_in_Actors) example from the akka documentation. 
Using this I am able to make the rest call. But I am not able to find out how to add custom request headers. I tried using ModeledCustomHeader, but still request is not having header. Here is my example.

```
final class ApiTokenHeader(token: String) extends ModeledCustomHeader[ApiTokenHeader] {
  override def renderInRequests = false
  override def renderInResponses = false
  override val companion = ApiTokenHeader
  override def value: String = token
}
object ApiTokenHeader extends ModeledCustomHeaderCompanion[ApiTokenHeader] {
  override val name = "apiKey"
  override def parse(value: String) = Try(new ApiTokenHeader(value))
}
```

This is how I am invoking,

```
def invokeHttpRequest(cmd: WSRequestCommand) = {
    val s: HttpRequest = HttpRequest(uri = cmd.url).addHeader(ApiTokenHeader(cmd.apiKey))

    sender ! http.singleRequest(s)
  }
```

Instead of addHeader, i tried with addHeaders(), but Seq(ApiTokenHeader) is not working as it is giving compilation error.

```
val s: HttpRequest = HttpRequest(uri = cmd.url, headers = Seq(ApiTokenHeader(cmd.apiKey)))
```

> Error:(55, 66) type mismatch;  found   :
>   Seq[com.myapp.http.core.ApiTokenHeader]  required:
>   scala.collection.immutable.Seq[akka.http.scaladsl.model.HttpHeader]
>       val s: HttpRequest = HttpRequest(uri = cmd.url, headers = Seq(ApiTokenHeader(cmd.apiKey)))
>   //.addHeader(ApiTokenHeader(cmd.apiKey))

Can someone help me to add multiple custom headers for my request ? What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: To be able to use the `Seq` your header needs to extend `HttpHeader`.

Comment: @EndeNeu Even in single addHeader method, the custom header I have added is not coming in the request.

Comment: Why do you have renderInRequest as false?

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out :) My mistake

Comment: First thing: you don't have to model custom headers, just use `RawHeader(name, value)` for one-off usages.

Comment: The type error is due to the unfortunate fact, that `scala.Seq` `!=` `scala.collection.immutable.Seq`. So, instead of `Seq(ApiTokenHeader(...))`, you can use either `ApiTokenHeader(...) :: Nil` to create a `List` (which is a subtype of `immutable.Seq`) or use `scala.collection.immutable.Seq(ApiTokenHeader(...))`.

Comment: Thanks @jrudolph. I was missed out the diff between Seq. It is working fine now. :)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

try do it simply
you can use the methods on HttpMessage with RawHeaders instead:

```
HttpRequest(GET, "/example.com/some")
   .withHeaders(
     RawHeader("X-CSRF-TOKEN", ...))
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `scala.collection.immutable.Seq` instead of the not immutable one

Also don't forget to set the `renderInRequests` and/or `renderInResponses` to true, otherwise your headers will disappear