# Add a custom header to scala WebSocketRequest

Tags: scala

I am following the example [here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/scala/http/client-side/websocket-support.html) to create a websocket client in Scala. I want to pass a custom header in the websocket request. I created a `CustomHeader` class by extending `HttpHeader`.

```
final class CustomHeader(headerName: String, headerValue: String) extends HttpHeader {
  override def name(): String = headerName

  override def value(): String = headerValue

  override def lowercaseName(): String = name.toLowerCase

  override def renderInRequests(): Boolean = true

  override def renderInResponses(): Boolean = true
}
```

Then in the client,

```
val headers = Seq(new CustomHeader("X-Auth-Token", authToken))
val request = new WebSocketRequest(uri = "ws://localhost:9035", extraHeaders = headers)
```

When I run `activator compile`, it throws the following error:

```
type mismatch;
[error]  found   : Seq[com.apple.geo.neutron.services.notification.event.CustomHeader]
[error]  required: scala.collection.immutable.Seq[akka.http.scaladsl.model.HttpHeader]
[error] Error occurred in an application involving default arguments.
[error]     val request = new WebSocketRequest(uri = "ws://localhost:9035", extraHeaders = headers)
```

How do I resolve this error, or add a custom header to the websocket request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question. Thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39444009/akka-http-client-custom-headers/40308475#40308475) thread, I found a working way to add custom headers. Here is what I did:

```
final class CustomHeader(headerValue: String) extends ModeledCustomHeader[CustomHeader] {
    override val companion = CustomHeader

    override def value(): String = headerValue

    override def renderInRequests(): Boolean = true

    override def renderInResponses(): Boolean = true
}

object CustomHeader extends ModeledCustomHeaderCompanion[CustomHeader] {
    override val name = "X-Auth-Token"

    override def parse(value: String) = Try(new CustomHeader(value))
}
```

And then, the websocket request is created as:

```
val headers = scala.collection.immutable.Seq(new CustomHeader(authToken))
val request = new WebSocketRequest(uri = "ws://localhost:9035", extraHeaders = headers)
```

Answer (score 0):

`Seq` here is not an immutable [`Seq`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/Seq.html). Try defining `headers` as:

```
val headers = scala.collection.immutable.Seq(new CustomHeader("X-Auth-Token", authToken))
```

Comment: While this solution solved this particular error, it resulted in another compilation error: method render in trait Renderable of type [R <: akka.http.impl.util.Rendering](r: R)r.type is not defined.